# Assigning value to an observation from table of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame of observations. i.e.

```
value 1,value 2
a,1
a,1
a,2
b,3
a,3
```

I now have an external DataFrame of values

```
_  ,a,b
1  ,10,20
2  ,30,40
3  ,50,60
```

What will be an efficient way to add to the first DataFrame the values from the indexed table?  i.e.:

```
value 1,value 2, new value
a,1,10
a,1,10
a,2,30
b,3,60
a,3,50
```

Comment: What does DF stand for?

Comment: DF stands for DataFrame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative solution using `.lookup()`. It's just one line, vectorized solution. suitable for large dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate some artificial data
# ================================
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(value1=np.random.choice('a b'.split(), 10), value2=np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=np.random.randn(10), b=np.random.randn(10)), columns=['a', 'b'], index=np.arange(1, 11))

df1

Out[178]: 
  value1  value2
0      a       6
1      b       3
2      b       5
3      a       8
4      b       7
5      b       9
6      b       9
7      b       2
8      b       7
9      b       8


df2

Out[179]: 
         a       b
1   2.5452  0.0334
2   1.0808  0.6806
3   0.4843 -1.5635
4   0.5791 -0.5667
5  -0.1816 -0.2421
6   1.4102  1.5144
7  -0.3745 -0.3331
8   0.2752  0.0474
9  -0.9608  1.4627
10  0.3769  1.5350



# processing: one liner lookup function
# =======================================================
# df1.value2 is the index and df1.value1 is the column
df1['new_values'] = df2.lookup(df1.value2, df1.value1)

Out[181]: 
  value1  value2  new_values
0      a       6      1.4102
1      b       3     -1.5635
2      b       5     -0.2421
3      a       8      0.2752
4      b       7     -0.3331
5      b       9      1.4627
6      b       9      1.4627
7      b       2      0.6806
8      b       7     -0.3331
9      b       8      0.0474
```

Comment: Won't you need to offset the index value by 1 as the index is 0 based?

Comment: @EdChum That's definitely a valid point, and it has been done when constructing the data `df2`. the index in `df1` doesn't matter since we just use the column values.

Comment: it was unclear to me whether the `'_'` was an actual column or the index from the OP's sample dfs but `lookup` is the better method here +1

Comment: This is perfect.
Are there any requirement for some of the columns to be an index?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your first and second dfs are `df` and `df1` respectively, you can merge on the matching columns and then mask the 'a' and 'b' conditions:

```
In [9]:
df = df.merge(df1, left_on=['value 2'], right_on=['_'])
a_mask = (df['value 2'] == df['_']) & (df['value 1'] == 'a')
b_mask = (df['value 2'] == df['_']) & (df['value 1'] == 'b')
df.loc[a_mask, 'new value'] = df['a'].where(a_mask)
df.loc[b_mask, 'new value'] = df['b'].where(b_mask)
df

Out[9]:
  value 1  value 2  _   a   b  new value
0       a        1  1  10  20         10
1       a        1  1  10  20         10
2       a        2  2  30  40         30
3       b        3  3  50  60         60
4       a        3  3  50  60         50
```

You can then drop the additional columns:

```
In [11]:
df = df.drop(['_','a','b'], axis=1)
df

Out[11]:
  value 1  value 2  new value
0       a        1         10
1       a        1         10
2       a        2         30
3       b        3         60
4       a        3         50
```

Another way is to define a func to perform the lookup:

```
In [15]:
def func(x):
    row = df1[(df1['_'] == x['value 2'])]
    return row[x['value 1']].values[0]

df['new value'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis = 1)
df

Out[15]:
  value 1  value 2  new value
0       a        1         10
1       a        1         10
2       a        2         30
3       b        3         60
4       a        3         50
```

**EDIT**

Using @Jianxun Li's `lookup` works but you have to offset the index as your index is `0` based:

```
In [20]:
df['new value'] = df1.lookup(df['value 2'] - 1, df['value 1'])
df

Out[20]:
  value 1  value 2  new value
0       a        1         10
1       a        1         10
2       a        2         30
3       b        3         60
4       a        3         50
```